# Spawn Enemies in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Something is going wrong in my mind, In my game , I want to instantiate enemies within library and put them on stage. so I create an EnemySpawner class and I put an instance from that class onto the stage . ( drag drop from library and give it a instance name). So here is the code for EnemySpawner class:

```
package scripts {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class EnemySpawner extends MovieClip {

    var positions: Array = new Array(); // clockwise spawn positions
    var enemies : Array = new Array();
    var spwan:Boolean=false;
    public function EnemySpawner() {
        positions.push(MovieClip(root).rightPos);
        positions.push(MovieClip(root).leftPos);
        enemies.push("Enemy1");// here is the problem
    }

    public function tick(): void {

    }
    public function doSpwan():void{

    }

}
```

}

So the problem issues here is , I want to randomly load enemies from library and instance them on stage , the design environment is something like this :

There are diffrent enemy movieclips in library with same blass class:

[image: pic from lib]

I don't want to assign each enemy a new class , for example I don't want to assign EnemyA Class to Enemy1 MovieClip Object and EnemyB Class to Enemy2 MovieClip . I want All Enemy MovieClip in the library share same class Enemy. so but using this , instantiate is hard task, I don't know how to instantiate enemies by using this method?

I know if I have separate class for each Enemy I can do this:

```
var e1 : Enemy1 = new Enemy1();
var e2 : Enemy2 = new Enemy2();
...

var e3 : Enemy3 = new Enemy3();
```

But I want do something like this:

```
//Pseudocode:
//Instantiate form library (Name Of Enemy1); //base class is enemy 1
//Instantiate form library (Name Of Enemy1); //base class is enemy 1
//Instantiate form library (Name Of Enemy1); //base class is enemy 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy task, actually. Assign enemies with **different** classes, then

```
// List classes in this Array.
var Enemies:Array = [Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3];

// Get a random class from the list.
var anIndex:int = Math.random() * Enemies.length;
var EnemyClass:Class = Enemies[anIndex];

// Spawn a random enemy.
// You can have a common superclass, or just use MovieClip or Sprite they are subclassed from.
var anEnemy:MovieClip = new EnemyClass;
```

Comment: Thanks for your code ,is there a way to not to assign different classes for enemies , i want a base class for all enemies , if you had worked with Unity3D , there is a mono behavior class that all enemies are use that just one class , so the logic is the same for all of them.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid There are different ways about it, but assigning unique classes to library items is unavoidable, this way or that.

Comment: " but assigning unique classes to library items is unavoidable" , not interesting issue about action script , anyway but I accept your answer , thanks dude !

Comment: I have make all Enemy1 , Enemy 2, Enemy 3 to extend my Own Enemy Class. this makes me to just update Enemy class , because of inheritance , problem solves simpler , but assigning unique classes to library items is unavoidable.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid Yep. One of the ways is to make a base enemy class then subclass is as many times as many different enemy variants you have there. You can compose a static **BaseEnemy.create()** method that instantiates and returns one of the available subslasses.